# OSX - socket connect redirection

Tags: c++, python, c, macos, sockets

In my application, I want to redirect certain applications connections.

In windows 7, you can modify the host and port used in a TCP/UDP connect call:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff571005(v=vs.85).aspx

I was going to look at the tsocks source, however the author says it's not working with asynchronous sockets. It's a rather old project, and was wondering if there's any modern API.

Is there any reliable solution for doing this in OSX lion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X, being a BSD-derived system, has [ipfw](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html), which is like Linux `iptables`. It lets you do this kind of thing at the OS level. The command-line tool is already installed on your mac (try `man ipfw`); Google will help you find graphical front ends for it.

Comment: I want to forward specific applications and I don't know which ports they will send traffic on, also I only know the target port after a query to the socks proxy has been made. In windows I solve it by intercepting any winsock connect call and modifying the destination after it's been provided by my socks server. So I definitely need to run some custom callback code to figure out which port to redirect to, do you think that's possible with ipfw? Thanks